# Can't figure out infinite loop

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I have a list of potential sites to place landing pads in a 2d array. They're kept in 2 ints, one for row and one for column. I need  to Randomly add a few landing sites from this list but for some reason it more often than not uses the same spots. I'd like to exclude these spots somehow so I used this loop but it locks up into an infinite loop for some reason and I just can't figure out why!

```
for(int j = 0; j < amountLandingPads; j++)
{
    int r = Random.Range(0,potSitesC.Length-1);

    while(roomType[potSitesR[r],potSitesC[r]] == (int)room.Landing)
    {
        r = Random.Range(0,potSitesC.Length-1);
    } 

    roomType[potSitesR[r],potSitesC[r]] = (int)room.Landing;

    //do more stuff
}
```

To me it looks like if the current site is already designated as  a landing site, randomly choose another until you find a site that isn't a landing pad, what am I doing wrong?

potSites.Length is always gonna be 20+ and ammountLandingPads is always potsites.Length/4 and minimum 1.

roomtype is the type of room at that position (in a 2d int array)

Comment: Can you please provide additional context as to what amountLandingPads, roomType, potSitesC and potSitesR are?

Comment: What if length of potSitesR and/or potSitesC is 1?  you'll always get the same random, right?  ;-)

Comment: [`Random.Range`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) gives a value in the half-open range `[min, max)` in the integer overloaded version, so you don't want to be subtracting 1 from the Length.

Comment: I suspect that potSites is equal to one so your randome number is always zero.

Comment: have edited in what the variables are. I now suspect that maybe potSitesR and potSitesC may not be filling correctly elsewhere making this moot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the same `int r` and also `potSitesR.Length` to decide both the row-coord and the column-coord of the landing site. This will end up always selecting positions from both `potSitesR` and `potSitesC` with the same indices, i.e. (potSitesR[1], potSitesC[1]), or (potSitesR[2], potSitesC[2]), and so on... and always within the potSitesR.Length range.

Try using a different value for both for more randomization. Here's example code:

```
for(int j = 0; j < amountLandingPads; j++)
    {
        //In the following statement
        //Removed -1 because int version is exclusive of second parameter
        //Changed it to potSitesR.Length (from potSitesC.Length)
        int r = Random.Range(0, potSitesR.Length);

        //second randomized number for column-randomization.
        int c = Random.Range(0, potSitesC.Length);  

        while (roomType[potSitesR[r],potSitesC[c]] == (int)room.Landing)    //using both randomized numbers
        {
            r = Random.Range(0, potSitesR.Length);  // r from potSitesR.Length
            c = Random.Range(0, potSitesC.Length);  // c from potSitesC.Length
        } 

        roomType[potSitesR[r], potSitesC[c]] = (int)room.Landing;

        //do more stuff
    }
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I see what you're getting at by those arrays just contain row and col information so at posittion (1,1) gives for example co-ord (5,4) as that's stored in it, and (2,2) a different co-ord, that is to say, I specifically need the same int r to be used in both arrays :)

Comment: @AlWyvern I see what you mean. I'll correct my answer to mean it will always select the coords stored at the *square* positions of the array. i.e. only the values (psR[1], psC[1]), or (psR[2], psC[2]), etc. I hope that makes sense. Do you *want* it to be that way?

Comment: Yeah,t hat array is working exactly as intended re picking out coordinates, though on closer inspection the array wasn't being populated correctly and was leading to the problems! Thanks for the help though :)